# Questions about how to make a heuristic and a goal state. feat 15-Puzzle problem in C

Tags: c

I'm doing a homework assignment for solving the 15 puzzle problem with A* search.

So the general idea of the 15 puzzle problem is that you have a blank zero tile that can be moved up, down, left or right and the goal is to get the puzzle in order from 1- 15 with the blank tile being the 16th tile on the puzzle.

I don't really understand the concept of a goal state, do I write in the program something like this to make a goal state?

```
for (i = 0; i < 16; i++)
{
goal_state[i] = i;
if(i == 16)
goal_state[i] = 0;
}
```

Furthermore, the idea of a heuristic, I understand that f(n) = g(n) + h(n) but how do I translate that to code? Does moving 1 tile increase g's value by 1? The more I move a tile the more g increases? h(n) is written to estimate the cost of the cheapest path from n to the goal.

How do I estimate the cost of the cheapest path? I'm looking for the cheapest path already.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define N 4
#define NxN (N*N)
#define TRUE 1
#define FALSE 0

struct node {
    int tiles[N][N];
    int f, g, h;
    short zero_row, zero_column;    /* location (row and colum) of blank tile 0 */
    struct node *next;
    struct node *parent;            /* used to trace back the solution */
};

int goal_rows[NxN];
int goal_columns[NxN];
struct node *start,*goal;
struct node *open = NULL, *closed = NULL;
struct node *succ_nodes[4];

void print_a_node(struct node *pnode) {
    int i,j;
    for (i=0;i<N;i++) {
        for (j=0;j<N;j++)
            printf("%2d ", pnode->tiles[i][j]);
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\n");
}

struct node *initialize(char **argv){
    int i,j,k,index, tile;
    struct node *pnode;

    pnode=(struct node *) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    index = 1;
    for (j=0;j<N;j++)
        for (k=0;k<N;k++) {
            tile=atoi(argv[index++]);
            pnode->tiles[j][k]=tile;
            if(tile==0) {
                pnode->zero_row=j;
                pnode->zero_column=k;
            }
        }
    pnode->f=0;
    pnode->g=0;
    pnode->h=0;
    pnode->next=NULL;
    pnode->parent=NULL;
    start=pnode;
    printf("initial state\n");
    print_a_node(start);

    pnode=(struct node *) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    goal_rows[0]=3;
    goal_columns[0]=3;

    for(index=1; index<NxN; index++){
        j=(index-1)/N;
        k=(index-1)%N;
        goal_rows[index]=j;
        goal_columns[index]=k;
        pnode->tiles[j][k]=index;
    }
    pnode->tiles[N-1][N-1]=0;         /* empty tile=0 */
    pnode->f=0;
    pnode->g=0;
    pnode->h=0;
    pnode->next=NULL;
    goal=pnode;
    printf("goal state\n");
    print_a_node(goal);

    return start;
}

/* merge unrepeated nodes into open list after filtering */
void merge_to_open() {
}

/*swap two tiles in a node*/
void swap(int row1,int column1,int row2,int column2, struct node * pnode){
}

/*update the f,g,h function values for a node */
void update_fgh(struct node *pnode){
}

/* 0 goes down by a row */
void move_down(struct node * pnode){
}

/* 0 goes right by a column */
void move_right(struct node * pnode){
}

/* 0 goes up by a row */
void move_up(struct node * pnode){
}

/* 0 goes left by a column */
void move_left(struct node * pnode){
}

/* expand a node, get its children nodes, and organize the children nodes using
 * array succ_nodes.
 */
void expand(struct node *selected) {
}

int nodes_same(struct node *a,struct node *b) {
    int flg=FALSE;
    if (memcmp(a->tiles, b->tiles, sizeof(int)*NxN) == 0)
        flg=TRUE;
    return flg;
}

/* Filtering. Some nodes in succ_nodes may already be included in either open
 * or closed list. Remove them. It is important to reduce execution time.
 * This function checks the (i)th node in succ_nodes array. You must call this
 & function in a loop to check all the nodes in succ_nodes.
 */
void filter(int i, struct node *pnode_list){
}


int main(int argc,char **argv) {
    int iter,cnt;
    struct node *copen, *cp, *solution_path;
    int ret, i, pathlen=0, index[N-1];

    solution_path=NULL;
    start=initialize(argv); /* init initial and goal states */
    open=start;

    iter=0;
    while (open!=NULL) {    /* Termination cond with a solution is tested in expand. */
        copen=open;
        open=open->next;  /* get the first node from open to expand */
        if(nodes_same(copen,goal)){ /* goal is found */
            do{ /* trace back and add the nodes on the path to a list */
                copen->next=solution_path;
                solution_path=copen;
                copen=copen->parent;
                pathlen++;
            } while(copen!=NULL);
            printf("Path (lengh=%d):\n", pathlen);
            copen=solution_path;
            ... /* print out the nodes on the list */
            break;
        }
        expand(copen);       /* Find new successors */
        for(i=0;i<4;i++){
            filter(i,open);
            filter(i,closed);
        }
        merge_to_open(); /* New open list */
        copen->next=closed;
        closed=copen;       /* New closed */
        /* print out something so that you know your
         * program is still making progress
         */
        iter++;
        if(iter %1000 == 0)
            printf("iter %d\n", iter);
    }
    return 0;
} /* end of main */
```

Comment: In the loop `for (i = 0; i < 16; i++)` the condition `(i == 16)` will never be true.

Answer (score 1):

> I don't really understand the concept of a goal state, do I write in the program something like this to make a goal state?

Yes, you could write this, although it would be better suited for the comparisons if the goal state and a node's state `tiles[N][N]` had the same dimensional shape.

> Furthermore, the idea of a heuristic, I understand that f(n) = g(n) + h(n) but how do I translate that to code? Does moving 1 tile increase g's value by 1?

That would definitely make sense.

> How do I estimate the cost of the cheapest path?

In order to find a least-cost path, the heuristic function is required to never overestimate the actual cost of the path to the goal. One possibility is to take the sum of the horizontal and vertical distances of each existing tile to its goal position; a weakness of this function is probably that it often severely underestimates the cost and thus doesn't help well in finding the best path fast. I just can't think of a good function here. But I however just read on the Wikipedia page for the [15-puzzle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/15_puzzle) that this is a commonly used heuristic.